# Group SQL output

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Ok. I am running a select with multiple CASEs in it. I am having an issue grouping my output (see example below).

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 1 -- UDA_AUTO_KEY 1 is the 'Company Value 1' value in the user_defined_attributes table that is connected to the rolodex table by the company_rolodex and companies tables
                THEN
                    'Company Value 1'
    END AS "Company Value 1",
    CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 2
                THEN
                    'Company Value 2'
    END AS "Company Value 2",
        CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 3
                THEN
                    'Company Value 3'
    END AS "Company Value 3",
   rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY, rdx.RDX_CONTACT_NAME,cmp.COMPANY_NAME -- other output values. So I want to know the person's name, their company and if they have Company Value 1, 2 or 3 checked, or all three.
FROM ROLODEX rdx  -- This is where the customer's name and email address are stored.
LEFT JOIN COMPANY_ROLODEX cprol ON cprol.RDX_AUTO_KEY = rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY  -- This connects the customers to the accounts on the 'companies' table
LEFT JOIN COMPANIES cmp ON cprol.CMP_AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY  -- This table will connect the customers on the rolodex table and the company name on the compaines table via the company rolodex table.
JOIN UDA_CHECKED uda ON uda.AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY -- This is where things mess up. Because there can be many check boxes on one company the company auto key apears many times on this table as the 'auto_key' value.
LEFT JOIN USER_DEFINED_ATTRIBUTES attr ON uda.UDA_AUTO_KEY = attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY -- This is to help define the 'company value' check boxes.
WHERE
rdx.EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'TEST@aol.com' -- I am using this where to disply that there are two line outputs and not one.
```

Here is a copy of the output:

```
Company Value 1                          8117   Tim Cartney Air, Inc.
                 Company Value 2         8117   Tim Cartney Air, Inc.
```

I would like this to be one line:

```
Company Value 1     Company Value 2      8117   Tim Cartney Air, Inc.
```

I want to get a list of every rolodex entry in the database and each value associated with them in one line, so I don't have duplicate values.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX` on every column:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 1 -- UDA_AUTO_KEY 1 is the 'Company Value 1' value in the user_defined_attributes table that is connected to the rolodex table by the company_rolodex and companies tables
                THEN
                    'Company Value 1'
    END) AS "Company Value 1",
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 2
                THEN
                    'Company Value 2'
    END) AS "Company Value 2",
...
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. When I add the Max, I get the error "not a single group group function"

and when I add a

GROUP BY rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY at the end I get the error:

"Not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: If you add `max` to every column you select, you don't need a `group by`. If you don't want to max ALL columns, the group by should consist of all columns which are not maxed.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using the 'MAX' and the 'group by'

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 1 -- UDA_AUTO_KEY 40 is the 'parts sales' value in the user_defined_attributes table that is connected to the rolodex table by the company_rolodex and companies tables
                THEN
                    'Company Value 1'
    END) AS "Company Value 1",
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 2
                THEN
                    'Company Value 2'
    END) AS "Company Value 2",
        MAX(CASE
        WHEN
            attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY = 3
                THEN
                    'Company Value 3'
    END) AS "Company Value 3",
rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY, rdx.RDX_CONTACT_NAME--,cmp.COMPANY_NAME -- other output values. So I want to know the person's name, their company and if they have Company Value 1, 2 or 3 checked, or all three.
FROM ROLODEX rdx  -- This is where the customer's name and email address are stored.
LEFT JOIN COMPANY_ROLODEX cprol ON cprol.RDX_AUTO_KEY = rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY  -- This connects the customers to the accounts on the 'companies' table
LEFT JOIN COMPANIES cmp ON cprol.CMP_AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY  -- This table will connect the customers on the rolodex table and the company name on the compaines table via the company rolodex table.
LEFT JOIN UDA_CHECKED uda ON uda.AUTO_KEY = cmp.CMP_AUTO_KEY -- This is where things mess up. Because there can be many check boxes on one company the company auto key apears many times on this table as the 'auto_key' value.
LEFT JOIN USER_DEFINED_ATTRIBUTES attr ON uda.UDA_AUTO_KEY = attr.UDA_AUTO_KEY -- This is to help define the 'company value' check boxes.
WHERE
rdx.EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'A1969Huey@aol.com' -- I am using this where to disply that there are two line outputs and not one.
GROUP BY rdx.RDX_AUTO_KEY, rdx.RDX_CONTACT_NAME
```

Comment: Rather than posting a new answer, it is better to accept the answer which helped you.